# Не работают команды контекстного меню

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть TreeView содержащий данные двух типов. Каждый тип данных имеет своё контекстное меню. К меню привязаны команды, но почему-то они не выполняются.

```
<Window
x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:BaseNS"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="525"
Height="350"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="GroupScreenContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Command="{Binding DeleteGroupCommand}" Header="Удалить Группу" />
    </ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ScreenContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding}">
        <MenuItem Command="{Binding DeleteScreenCommand}" Header="Удалить экран" />
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:ScreenModel}">
                <StackPanel ContextMenu="{StaticResource ScreenContextMenu}">
                    <Label Background="Aqua" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:GroupModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <StackPanel ContextMenu="{StaticResource GroupScreenContextMenu}">
                    <Label Background="Green" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Screens}">
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label>Screens</Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

```
public class GroupModel : TreeItemBase
{
}

public class ScreenModel : TreeItemBase
{
}

public class TreeItemBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TreeItemBase> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<TreeItemBase> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; OnPropertyChanged("Items"); }
    }
public class Command : ICommand
{
    private Action _action;

    public Command(Action p_action)
    {
        _action = p_action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_action != null)
        {
            _action();
        }
    }
}

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }


}


public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<TreeItemBase> _screens;


    public ObservableCollection<TreeItemBase> Screens
    {
        get { return _screens; }
        set
        {
            _screens = value; OnPropertyChanged("Screens");
        }
    }

    ICommand DeleteGroupCommand;
    ICommand DeleteScreenCommand;

    private void DeleteGroup()
    {
        Screens.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    private void DeleteScreen()
    {
        Screens.RemoveAt(3);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ScreenModel screen = new ScreenModel() { Name = "screen" };
        Screens = new ObservableCollection<TreeItemBase>();
        Screens.Add(screen);
        GroupModel screen1 = new GroupModel() { Name = "fld1", Items = new ObservableCollection<TreeItemBase>() { new ScreenModel() { Name = "IP-54" }, new ScreenModel() { Name = "IP-86" } } };
        Screens.Add(screen1);
        GroupModel screen11 = new GroupModel() { Name = "fld2", Items = new ObservableCollection<TreeItemBase>() { new ScreenModel() { Name = "IP-10" }, new ScreenModel() { Name = "IP-38" } } };
        Screens.Add(screen11);
        GroupModel screen111 = new GroupModel() { Name = "fld3", Items = new ObservableCollection<TreeItemBase>() { new ScreenModel() { Name = "IP-92" }, new ScreenModel() { Name = "IP-99" }, new GroupModel() { Name = "fld6", Items = new ObservableCollection<TreeItemBase>() { new ScreenModel() { Name = "IP-55" } } } } };
        Screens.Add(screen111);
        DeleteScreenCommand = new Command(DeleteScreen);
        DeleteGroupCommand = new Command(DeleteGroup);
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Несколько часов пытался заставить это работать, но ничего не получилось.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668654/relativesource-binding-from-a-tooltip-or-contextmenu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583507/wpf-binding-a-contextmenu-to-an-mvvm-command

Comment: Вообщем, решений хватает, если поискать

Comment: Пробовал вариант с использованием PlacementTarget.Tag, но он у меня не заработал. Наверно это из-за HierarchicalDataTemplate, т.к. неопределенная вложенность элементов.

Comment: А вариант с `BindingProxy` пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал. Ничего не выходит. если делать как в вышеперечисленных статьях, я сделал меню кнопки, то работает, в treeview же не хочет. Вот выложил проект http://my-files.ru/yqfjec кто хочет смотрите.

Comment: Файл был удалён. Причина удаления: Файл является вредоносным ПО.

Comment: Файл удалили как вредоносный, попробуй поместить в архив или залить на файлообменник

Answer (score 1):

Получилось, но пришлось выкручиваться задавая DataContext через Свойство Tag. Шаблоны изменил так:

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:ScreenModel}">
                <StackPanel ContextMenu="{StaticResource ScreenContextMenu}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
                    <Label Background="Aqua" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:GroupModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
                <StackPanel ContextMenu="{StaticResource GroupScreenContextMenu}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
                    <Label Background="Green" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Сами меню так:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="GroupScreenContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.Tag}">
        <MenuItem Command="{Binding DeleteGroupCommand}" Header="Удалить Группу"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ScreenContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.Tag}">
        <MenuItem Command="{Binding DeleteScreenCommand}" Header="Удалить экран" />
    </ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Об этом как раз и написано по тем ссылкам, которые приводил. То, что у вас сразу не заработало связано скорее всего с тем, что в том коде, который вы привели, комманды `DeleteGroupCommand`, `DeleteScreenCommand` поля а не свойства.